# Rails console ignores newlines in ActiveRecord:Relation object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I was going through the [AR query interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and from it I got the impression that the Rails console should be interpreting the \n in the output from the .explain command as a newline, rather than printing it as raw text on the screen. Reading a query on one single line is inconvenient to say the least.

I can "fix" the formatting issue by prepending "print" to any ActiveRecord::Relation object output to the console, as in the canonical example:

```
print User.joins(:posts).explain
```

Is it supposed to work that way by default, or am I doing something wrong? Do people always stick to prepending print?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the rails console displays the `\n` characters (rather than rendering) them by default. I always add `print` exactly as you have done.

Comment: Thanks! Guess that answers it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems normal.

```
>> hi = "hello\nworld"
=> "hello\nworld"
>> hi
=> "hello\nworld"
>> puts hi
hello
world
=> nil
```

If you just type a variable or method, it shows you a raw data dump of the value or return value.